# Using linq to set multiple elements

Tags: .net, linq

I'm trying to change all cells in a table that has a StyleID of "foo" to "bar".  I'm using the following expression to get all the cells in a table who has a StyleID="foo".  I verified my narrowing function works by doing the following

```
Dim count As Integer = 
   <Table>...<Row>...<Cell>.Where(Function(c) c.@ss:StyleID = "foo").Count
```

when I run this, it returns the correct number of cells for the dataset.

However, when I execute the following code, nothing happens.

```
<Table>...<Row>...<Cell>
    .Where(Function(c) c.@ss:StyleID = "foo").@ss:StyleID = "bar"
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the StyleID of the Where method, not each cell. You need to iterate all cells and set the StyleID of each one of them.

Comment: So he needs to put the result of the query in a `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

```
.Where(Function(c) c.@ss:StyleID = "foo")
.ToList()
.ForEach(/*do stuff here*/)
```

I don't actually recognise your syntax. Is it VB.NET?

In C#:

```
.Where(c => c.StyleID == "foo")
.ToList()
.ForEach(c => c.StyleID = "bar");
```

Comment: +1 You can remove the ToList calls, making this more efficient.

Comment: @usr. IEnumerable has no ForEach, hence the ToList().

Comment: indeed! I always forget that this extension only exists in my own projects :)

Comment: @usr. Same here. I had to Google it before replying just to be sure MS hadn't added it in the later framework versions! :)